# Better way to create BsonBinary for java mongodb

Tags: java, mongodb, mongo-java-driver

There are 2 codesnippets:

```
    BsonBinaryCodec binaryCodec = new BsonBinaryCodec();
    ByteBuffer byteBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream));
    BsonReader bsonReader = new BsonBinaryReader(byteBuffer);
    BsonBinary content = binaryCodec.decode(bsonReader, DecoderContext.builder().build());
```

and

```
    byte[] buffer = IOUtils.toByteArray(inputStream);
    BsonBinary content = new BsonBinary(buffer);
```

Which approach is better and why?
I don't understand, in which cases I should use BsonBinaryCodec.